# How would I access a contract's public property (variable) using web3.js?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I'm trying to get a variable called "entryAmount". I've tried many methods, like calling it as a method, but it doesn't work.

A part of the solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ContractName {
    address public owner;
    ...
    uint256 public entryAmount = 0.01 ether;
```

Part of the abi:

```
{
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "entryAmount",
    "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
```

In the abi it states that entryAmount is a function but I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: contract.methods.entryAmount is not a function`

My JS Code:

```
...
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, ca)
console.log(contract.methods.entryAmount().call())
...
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.